# Change javascript addEventListener from 'wheel' to 'scroll'

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm trying to change this javascript event to happen on scroll rather than the mouse wheel. I've tried changing

```
window.addEventListener('wheel',function (e)
```

to

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function (e)
```

and then on this line changing

```
var scrollVal = e.deltaY * 0.001;
```

to

```
var scrollVal = e.scrollTop * 0.001;
```

But it's still not working. This is the full code:

```
window.addEventListener('wheel',function (e) { 
if(!parallaxLocked){
  var scrollVal = e.deltaY * 0.001;

  introContentDist -= (scrollVal * (window.innerHeight * 0.2));
  mainContentDist -= (scrollVal * window.innerHeight);

  if(mainContentDist < window.innerHeight){
    if(mainContentDist > 0){
      var distanceCoveredPercentage = mainContentDist / window.innerHeight;
      TweenMax.to(introDiv, 0.1, {y: introContentDist+"px", opacity: 1 * distanceCoveredPercentage}); 
      TweenMax.to(belowFold, 0.1, {y: mainContentDist+"px"}); 
      window.scrollTo(0,0); 

      if(!firstSlideFadedUp){
        if(mainContentDist < window.innerHeight * 0.5){ // if parallaxed up 50%
          contentSections[0].className = 'airpoints-module -active'; // fade in first section
        }
      }

      if(!stickyLogosFadedUp){
        if(mainContentDist < window.innerHeight * 0.25){ // if parallaxed up 75%
          stickyLogo.className = 'c-sticky-logo fade-in'; // fade in sticky logo changer
          stickyLogosFadedUp = true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      // when scrolled to end, lock divs to final place
      TweenMax.to(introDiv, 0.1, {y: "-30%"+"px"}); 
      TweenMax.to(belowFold, 0.1, {y: "0%"});
      parallaxLocked = true;

      // now that everything is locked in place
      setupScrollLogoChanger(); 
    }
  }
}
});
```

Comment: you can use `$(window).off('wheel')` and `$(window).on('scroll',function(e){ /*Your code*/});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `scrollTop` property on the scroll event. You can use `window.scrollY` instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) { 
    if(!parallaxLocked){
        var scrollVal = window.scrollY * 0.001;
        ...
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ya34o8wz/